# Why install latest version of chrome everytime code is pushed - gitlab-ci

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have seen many examples of gitlab-ci.yml files where as a part of the build, people install the latest version of chrome. So that means on every single push to the repository, the server is downloading a new version of chrome for that instance to run. For example, this is what I have in my gitlab-ci.yml file now:

```
# Installs Chrome
- wget -q -O — https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - 
- echo ‘deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main’ | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
- apt-get update
- apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y
```

Why would people do this? Would this not slow down and possibly halt your builds if a lot of developers are pushing code at the same time? Why am I seeing this, instead of just downloading chrome on the server beforehand, so your builds will run faster?

Comment: How else would you verify if your code runs on the latest Chrome?

Comment: @KonradBotor by installing chrome in your image, updating your image when a new chrome is released and replacing the `apt-get install` by `apt-get upgrade` so that it only downloads if your image needs updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing it because, most probably, the code is not run on a pre-existing server but on a docker image that doesn't contain that binary. If it would run on a server than the lines in question would only update the package.

If you are experiencing performance problem you may prepare your own docker images that have that package already installed but it's hard to say why this wasn't done before. Maybe performance problems weren't noticed before or the code comes from a tutorial that didn't want to focus on how to create images.

Answer (score 1):

In light of your response to my comment I can think of three possible explanations:

- Person who created gitlab-ci.yml did not think of the possibility of creating their custom image with Chrome
- Person who created gitlab-ci.yml does not know how to create custom Docker images
- Person who created gitlab-ci.yml decided that they did not want to be bothered with creating a new version of the custom image every time new version of Chrome is released - possibly because in their mind CI is something you set up once and then forget about it unless there are errors reported.

Edit: It was not my intention to accuse anybody of laizness or ineptness. Let me elaborate:

- Not thinking of a particular solution to a given problem at a given time does not automatically make a person inept. I'm sure everybody has at least once in their live solve a problem in some way, only to either later realize or have it pointed to them that there is a faster/better/more elegant solution and wonder why they did not think of it, because it's so obvious. Nobody is at 100% all the time.
- Not knowing a particular tool does not make a person inept. As far as I know understanding Docker is not a prerequisite of using Gitlab CI (or any other CI for that matter). The person setting up the CI may not know it if it's not used anywhere else in the project nad may not have time to learn it, given the time alloted for the task of setting up the CI (which is usually not done by them, but someone higher in hierarchy).
- My last point could have been worded better, I admit. What I meant is that, in my mind, the CI is something one configures with the intention of it runninng autonomously unless something unexpected happens or the outside conditions change. For example I've set up several Jenkins jobs for different project for mantaining the test environments. The basic template is always the same - checkout code from repository, build it, run the tests, archive logs on the test environment and finally deploy the new build to the test environment. The job always set up to send emails to predefined list of people in case of failure. After the setup is done, I set up some trigger for it (timer or webhook) and forget about it unless I get an email about failure or the way project needs to be built or deployed has changed. I do not think that makes me lazy - I think it makes me efficient, since I now have more time for other tasks - ones that cannot be easily automated (if at all).

Comment: That is very harsh, the answer shouldn't suggest that the person who created that solution is lazy or inept.

Comment: I'm both lazy and inept. I love this answer because I've made all these mistakes and I made them because I either 1) didn't know any better or 2) didn't feel like rolling my own containers because the builds kept shifting underneath me.